# Why cannot thumbnails be created by image-dired?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, images

when I view `png` images in Dired-mode there is no problem but when I try to view the thumbnail of it (`C-t d`), it fails and throws this error: `could not create thumb of <filename>`.

`M-:` of `dynamic-library-alist` returns these lists:

```
((xpm "libxpm.dll" "xpm4.dll" "libXpm-nox4.dll") (png "libpng16.dll" "libpng16-16.dll") (tiff "libtiff-5.dll" "libtiff3.dll" "libtiff.dll") (jpeg "libjpeg-9.dll") (gif "libgif-7.dll") (svg "librsvg-2-2.dll") (gdk-pixbuf "libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll") (glib "libglib-2.0-0.dll") (gobject "libgobject-2.0-0.dll") (gnutls "libgnutls-28.dll" "libgnutls-26.dll") (libxml2 "libxml2-2.dll" "libxml2.dll") (zlib "zlib1.dll" "libz-1.dll"))
```

What fundamental point am I missing?

**Notes:**

- Windows 7 32 bit
- Emacs 24.4

Comment: Could it be you haven't got `imagemagick` installed? IIRC the thumbnails are created with the `convert` command it provides.

Comment: @wasamasa is it a requirement? I will try to install it now but what do I need to make emacs aware of it on Winodws machine? apart from adding it to path variables

Comment: According to `image-dired.el` the `imagemagick` software is indeed a requirement since it needs its `convert` and `mogrify` executables.  Therefore, install it, extend `PATH` if necessary and make sure you can invoke the commands in a shell, then it should work in any subsequent Emacs session.

Comment: yep, it worked well. Feel free to answer this post for the benefit of future users as well.

Comment: Good, did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While most issues with images in Emacs on Microsoft Windows are caused by missing shared libraries, this one is the fault of missing executables.  `image-dired` requires the [image-magick](http://imagemagick.org/) software which provides (among others) the `convert` and `mogrify` executables.  Installing it and modifying `PATH` to allow you to launch these in a terminal should do the trick, any subsequent Emacs session will then be able to display thumbnails in `dired` for you.

Comment: I noticed also by installation of imagemagick it offers a default option to add binary folder of executables to your path so that you don't need to add it manually by yoruself.