# Thumbnails not displaying with image-dired

Tags: debugging, image-dired

**Background:** I recently found out about `image-dired`, so I'm playing around with it and trying to get it to work. It seems to *mostly* work, but when I `image-dired` into a directory (we'll call it `~/Documents/Images`) that has a handful of images it only shows the thumbnail for the first image in the directory, and in the minibuffer returns the error:

`error in process sentinel: Wrong type argument: processp, [nil 24302 41099 85815 nil image-dired-thumb-queue-run nil nil 0]`

**What I've done so far:** after reading [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/why-cannot-thumbnails-be-created-by-image-dired), I thought that maybe my problem could be triggered by not having `imagemagick` installed. However, after installing it (which was a pain) and confirming that emacs can see `imagemagick` by testing `M-! convert`, I get the same behavior. I've found (what I think is) the source code for `image-dired` [here](https://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/image-dired.el), and I can see that there is a function called `image-dired-thumb-queue-run`, but I don't know enough lisp to know what it's doing or if it's the function causing my problems.

**Questions:**

1. What is causing my error?
2. How can I get normal behavior from `image-dired`? (i.e., display all thumbnails for a given directory)

**Notes:** I'm using Emacs 26.3 (with built-in image-dired) on Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: In the time since I asked this question, I have lost the ability to reproduce this problem. `image-dired` works just fine for me now (Emacs 29.1 on MacOS Sonoma 14.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

M-x image-dired-jump-thumbnail-buffer

M-x image-dired-dired-toggle-marked-thumbs

it works for me.

GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0, NS appkit-2113.60
Version 12.7 (Build 21G816)) of 2023-11-20