# Executable image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program not found on Darwin, macOS

Tags: osx, path, zsh, image-dired

total Emacs newbie here. When I try:

```
M-x image-dired RET FOLDER RET
```

The minibuffer shows this error:

```
Executable image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program not found
```

When I check the `*Messages*` buffer it says:

```
Error running timer ‘image-dired-thumb-queue-run’: 
(error "Executable image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program not found")
Unable to load image (image :type jpeg :file /Users/myUser/.emacs.d/image-dired/flower_5d5bfef050581bb59e32e9a4ef593dbd.thumb.jpg :relief 2 :margin 2)
```

and the `*image-dired*` buffer shows no thumbnails (although I can move through the buffer as if there were thumbnails).

I already installed `ImageMagick` as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/why-cannot-thumbnails-be-created-by-image-dired)

```
> magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-23 Q16-HDRI x86_64 2022-02-05 https://imagemagick.org
```

and my PATH already points to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
> echo $PATH
/Users/myUser/.cabal/bin
/Users/myUser/.ghcup/bin
/Users/myUser/opt/anaconda3/bin
/Users/myUser/opt/anaconda3/condabin
/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/myUser/.local/bin
/Users/myUser/.cabal/bin
/Users/myUser/.ghcup/bin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/opt/X11/bin
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

where `magick`, `convert` and `mogrify` are

```
> which magick
/usr/local/bin/magick
> which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
> which mogrify
/usr/local/bin/mogrify
```

I googled it but couldn't find any similar issue.

**How could I fix this?**

BTW, I'm using `zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)`, I don't know if that's relevant.

Notes:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- GNU Emacs 27.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by GUI apps on macOS only inherit the default minimal environment variables. You can check this by run `M-: (getenv "PATH")` and `M-: (executable-find image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program)`.

If so, the most convenient way to solve it is to use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), or you can try to manually set `image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program` to the absolute path like `(setq image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program "/usr/local/bin/convert")`

Comment: Yes, [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) did the job. Thank you!